# Can we use AM HM for negative numbers

Tags: inequality

Can we use AM HM inequality for negative since my teacher told me AM GM is only applicable for non negatives but he didn't told in AM HM

Comment: Did you try some examples? E.g. with two negative numbers or one positive and one negative?

Comment: Oh got it it doesnt hold thanks

Comment: In fact, $$\frac{a+b}2 \geqslant \frac{2}{\frac1a+\frac1b} \implies \frac{(-a)+(-b)}2 \leqslant \frac{2}{\frac1{(-a)}+\frac1{(-b)}}$$

Comment: And with $a+b \approx 0$ the harmonic mean becomes arbitrary large.